Issue with Single Sign-On (SSO) Implementation in WPF Application
I'm encountering an issue with the implementation of Single Sign-On (SSO) in our WPF application, and I'd appreciate some guidance or insights from the community.
Here's a breakdown of our setup:

We have a main WPF application that utilizes ADFS with MSAL for login purposes.
Within this application, we've developed a custom WebView2 control, leveraging the PublicClientApplication to integrate with our custom control.
Additionally, we provide support for hosting web applications within our WPF application. Recently, we incorporated an Angular (SPA) web application into our WPF environment, which also uses ADFS with MSAL for login.
Our objective is to enable Single Sign-On (SSO) functionality in the hosted web application, utilizing the cache generated during the login process of our WPF application.

We've managed to achieve this integration successfully. However, we encountered a roadblock when attempting to implement automatic login in the WPF application under specific conditions. More specifically:

We aim to automate the login process in the WPF application if a certain flag, let's call it "SingleSignOnUser," is set to True by the user. This is accomplished using the AcquireTokenSilent API provided by PublicClientApplication.
The issue arises when calling AcquireTokenSilent: it doesn't display any prompts at the start of the WPF application, and consequently, our MSIS Auth Cookies are not being set in our custom WebView2 control. As a result, we're unable to achieve Single Sign-On (SSO) functionality in the hosted web application.

It's important to note that we retain the user data folder in its path, and we're not deleting it along with the cache. In theory, the WebView2 control should be able to capture cookies from this data or AcquireTokenSilent API should be able to set cookies for our custom WebView2 control.
Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, or perhaps have insights into what might be causing this behavior?
Expectation: The WebView2 control should be able to capture cookies from this data or AcquireTokenSilent API should be able to set cookies for our custom WebView2 control.
